# Is there a way to batch copy multiple file's 'Where From' metadata to 'Comments' metadata?

Tags: macos, metadata

I'm looking for a way to batch copy individual files 'Where From' metadata to 'Comments' metadata.

Only found xattr that can delete metadata, couldn't figure out how xattr can copy the info from 'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms' to 'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment'.

I have more than 10,000 files, hoping to find a way to batch process them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand what you want and I think you can do it with `exiftool`, but please check on a couple of copies of files in a completely separate directory.

So, to copy the `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms` to `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment` for a document called `file.pdf`, you can use:

```
exiftool '-MDItemWhereFroms>MDItemFinderComment' file.pdf
```

Then you can check with:

```
mdls file.pdf
```

If you have thousands to do, you can specify a directory to start in and `-r` to recurse, something like:

```
exiftool '-MDItemWhereFroms>MDItemFinderComment' -r .
```

You can also limit it to certain files.

---

On `macOS`, it is probably simplest to install `exiftool` with **homebrew** using:

```
brew install exiftool
```

Comment: OMG thank you!
This is exactly what I was looking to do.
You're a life saver!

Comment: Hi @mark-setchell , if I need to reverse and copy `comments` to `where from`, is there a way to batch process them?
Exiftool doesn't support writing to `com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms` so I'm out of luck there.